# Show a tooltip with more info when mousover a MVC3 Razor WebGrid row

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

I have a grid with a list of persons. On mouseover a certain persons row I would like to show additional info (photo, address etc) in a tooltip. 
All the needed data exist in the model, but I don't know how to add the tooltip functionality inside the grid. I also wonder if the jquery ui tooltip is a good choice for this?

TIA :)

Comment: yes, i would use the jquery tooltip.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code sample to show tool-tip in asp.net mvc webgrid :

```
grid.Column("LongTextColumn", "Column Header Here"
            , format: (item) => Html.Raw("<abbr style='background-color:Beige;'
              title='" + item.LongTextColumn + "'>" + item.OtherModelColumn + 
              "</abbr>"), canSort: false)
```

Below version shows 25 characters of long comment / text column and shows rest of the full text as a tool-tip. It also take care of text shorter than 25 characters.

```
grid.Column("ModelItem.LongTextColumn", "Column Header", format: (item) => 
             Html.Raw("<abbr style='background-color:Beige;' title='" +
             item.ModelItem.LongTextColumn + "'>" +
             item.ModelItem.LongTextColumn.PadRight(25).Substring(0, 25) + 
             "</abbr>"), canSort: false)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try the BeautyTips jquery plugin. It's a good one to load ajax content. It has a lot of features, and it even supports HTML5. Check out their demos [here](http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html).

Comment: Looks promising thnx :) I still wonder how to get the tooltip inside the webgrid so I keep my question open.

Answer (score 0):

Derived from the answer of Mayank, here's a somewhat cleaner version that worked for me:

```
grid.Column("Column Header", format: (item) => Html.Raw("<div title='" + item.ModelAttribute1 + "'>" + item.ModelAttribute2 + "</div>"))
```